# Extract ip addres and other stuff from a bind log string using python

Tags: python, regex

Have a bind log string like this one

```
'09-Sep-2013 10:22:42.540 queries: info: client 10.12.12.66#39177: query: google.com IN AXFR -T (10.10.10.11)\n',
```

Use a regex to extract the date,ip address and query

```
re.compile("(.*?) queries.*client (.*?): query: (.*?) IN")
```

and get the following output

```
[('09-Sep-2013 10:22:42.540','10.12.12.66#39177','google.com')]
```

Almost great, but just can't get rid of the hash port tail off the ip address. Like this one #39177. Maybe someone can help me with the right pattern, that returns the ip address without the hash and port stuff.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one (just added `#\d+` after the IP address saving group):

```
"(.*?) queries.*client (.*?)#\d+: query: (.*?) IN"
```

DEMO:

```
>>> s = '09-Sep-2013 10:22:42.540 queries: info: client 10.12.12.66#39177: query: google.com IN AXFR -T (10.10.10.11)\n'
>>> re.search("(.*?) queries.*client (.*?)#\d+: query: (.*?) IN", s).groups()
('09-Sep-2013 10:22:42.540', '10.12.12.66', 'google.com')
```